# Batch File to copy/paste excel file with dynamic name

Tags: excel, batch-file

I'm very new to writing batch files, I'm looking to find a way to copy an excel file from one file location to another

I'm able to write a script where it says save-as in the new location but I'm looking for something more elegenat.

I've found the below and it works but my filename is dynamic, I find it in excel by looking for with * on the end ie *filename* *

```
copy c:\work\source\*abc* c:\stackoverflow\target
```

Is there a similar format for batch files? Can I define the parent format and add the *

Comment: copy C:\work\source\\*.xls c:\path

Comment: The file is generated by a program in this case its Xyasud_date_timecreated. I'd like to define the date and then use * for the time created since its a few seconds off each day

Comment: This works for me: copy c:\work\source\myfile_date_*.xls c:\location

Answer (score 0):

```
set mydate=somedate   
set myfile="Xyasud_%mydate%_*.xls"
copy %myfile% c:\location
```